# TypeError: $("#city").autocomplete is not a function

Tags: autocomplete

This is my php page coding:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addclasskillclass.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/attachevent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addcss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabtastic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax-dynamic-list1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backtotop.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="calendar/dhtmlgoodies_calendar.css?random=20051112" media="screen"></LINK>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="calendar/dhtmlgoodies_calendar.js?random=20060118"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();   
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#toTop').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},600);
    }); 
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#city").autocomplete("autocityuser.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>

<form method="get" name="frm1" id="frm1" action="#">
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" style="width:160px;" size="30" />
</form>
```

When i load this page the FF shows me this error:
TypeError: $("#city").autocomplete is not a function

I've applied the same code for `autocomplete` on another page (but with less js imports) and it is working fine.
but it is showing me error on this page, may be beacause some js is conflicting.
Can anyone help me to solve this error???

P.S. I forgot mention that i have 2 forms on this page both with different ids and names

P.S. I still don't know what the problem was , but fortunately 
**The problem is solved**,
i just put below code at the end of the page and everything works perfect.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#city").autocomplete("autocityuser.php", {
            selectFirst: true
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: -1 for including your own answer in the question and not answering separately.

Answer (score 0):

You're using part of the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) (autocomplete) but it doesn't look like you have the jQuery libraries in place.

Try including the following scripts:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script></script>
```

EDIT

I think your basic approach is wrong.

You want to call the PHP to get your autocomplete options using AJAX and stick the echoed value into a variable `availableTags`. Then you want to set up your autocomplete.

Something like this (not tested):

```
var availableTags;
$.get("autocityuser.php", function(data){
      availableTags = data;  // You need to format the data either here or in your PHP
});
$("#city").autocomplete({source: availableTags});​
```

Comment: when i apply $('#city').hide(); it doesn't shows any error,which means jQuery is working

Comment: @pnr Try something basic like `$('#city').hide();` to see if the jQuery is working. And is this the sort of effect you're after? `http://jsfiddle.net/2GzFL/`

Comment: @pnr  But does it hide the city input when you run? If it doesn't, jQuery isn't working!!

Comment: I am looking for same thing http://jsfiddle.net/2GzFL/
Also after applying `$('#city').hide();` it is **Hiding** the city input.

Comment: @pnr  Well, that's good it's hiding :)  Why not just copy the demo version of `autocomplete` using the link in my answer? You have `select:first` which is not an option for the UI version. Are you perhaps using the deprecated plugin version (see: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete)?  And what is the PHP doing for you?

Comment: Here is php coding :
$q=$_GET['q'];
$my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_name') or die("Database Error");
$sql="SELECT city_name FROM city_mst WHERE city_name LIKE '$my_data%' ORDER BY city_name";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($result)
 {
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['p_name']."\n";
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Are any other libs using $ and overwriting jQuery's usage of it? Maybe, try `jQuery("#city").autocomplete`

Comment: This is possible. If Martin's suggestion works, you could try putting all your code in a closure like so: `(function($){....}(jQuery));`

Comment: Same Error
TypeError: jQuery("#city").autocomplete is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem recently recently. I found that two different version of jquery lib file was included from two different place.

Look for extra inclusion using firebug as js library could have been included from other included files.